# Problem installing QGIS on Mavericks. Says I need 10.6.8

Tags: qgis, installation, mac

Trying to install QGIS for first time on a Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks). Loaded up all the prerequisites (GDAL, etc.) but the QGIS installer tells me "QGIS requires Mac OS X 10.6.8.". Saw that QGIS is supposed to work on Mavs but can't find what I'm doing wrong.  Help??

Comment: Did you download the QGIS installer from [Kyngchaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis)?

Comment: Yes.  That's where I got it. It's version 2.0.1-4 dated 2013-11-22.  It's the one for Snow Leopard

Comment: That's my problem isn't it.  Should have done Lion version...D'oh.

Comment: Yes, you are not on Snow Leopard...